# How to use a Local Variable everywhere

Tags: typescript

So I am making an economy system, and I have run into an error, I am trying to make an inventory command where the user can see their inventory. I am trying to declare an item, then check if the user has it, if not, it will mark `has` as false, if so, then it does not do anything. I can not get it to update, it just re-declares the var.

```
      let userInv = {};
      for (const [name, item] of Object.entries(SHOP_ITEMS)) {
        if (!(await potatoKV.get<boolean>(`${name}-${message.author.id}`))) {
          userInv = {
            rifle: {
              name: item.name,
              description: item.description,
              has: false
            }
          };
          // idk what next here
        }
      }
      const fields = await Promise.all(
        Object.entries(userInv)
          .filter(([, item]) => (item.has = false))
          .map(async ([name, item]) => ({
            name: item.name,
            value: item.description
          }))
      );
```

This script is in Typescript

Comment: You're trying to reassign a `const` variable.

Comment: should i change it into a `let` variable?

Comment: `const` means _constant_, so if you want to change the value assigned then `const` isn't going to work. `let userInv = {}` will allow the variable to to be assigned new values. But if you are really using typescript then you should have seen this type error `Cannot assign to 'userInv' because it is a constant.(2588)` which would have been a big clue.

Comment: `(item.has = false)` is an assignment, not a comparison. This should be `(item.has === false)` or simply `!item.has`.